# Device Not coming in MEM portal or are with partially Workload shifted. How fix it?

Tags: azure, powershell, intune

I Tried below PowerShell.

Created a Powershell Script:

- **DeleteEnrollment.PS1**

```
## Create Log

Function Write-Log 
{
    Param 
    (
    [string]$Message
    )

    $Logfilepath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\CoMgmtFixLog"
    $Logfile = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\CoMgmtFixLog\CoMgmtFixLog.log"

    If (!(Test-Path $Logfilepath))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Logfilepath -Force | Out-Null
    }

    If (!(Test-Path $Logfile))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $Logfile -Force | Out-Null
    }

    $Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    $mgs = "$Stamp $Message"
    Add-Content $Logfile -Value $mgs
}

## Create TimeStamp in Registry
Function Create-Timestamp
{
    param
    (
        [String]$RegKeypath,
        [String]$RegKeyName,
        [String]$RegKeyValue
    )
    $ComgmtFixHive = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\CoMgmtFix'
    $Step = "$ComgmtFixHive\$RegKeypath"

    If (!(Test-Path $ComgmtFixHive))
    {
        New-Item -Path $ComgmtFixHive -Force | Out-Null
    }
    
    If(!(Test-Path $Step))
    {
        New-Item -Path $Step -Force | Out-Null
    }
    If($Step -and $RegKeyName -and $RegKeyValue)
    {
        New-ItemProperty -Path $Step -Name $RegKeyName -Value $RegKeyValue -PropertyType 'String' -force -ea SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    }
    New-ItemProperty -Path $Step -Name 'ExecutionTimeStap' -Value (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") -PropertyType 'String' -force -ea SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    
}

## Script Block ##
$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
Write-Log "=========== Begining of Log - $Stamp =========="

## Retrieving Enrollment GUID
(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Provisioning\OMADM\Accounts\*' | select Pschildname).pschildname | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\CoMgmtFixLog\EnrollmentGUID.txt'
$DeviceEnrollmentID = Get-Content 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\CoMgmtFixLog\EnrollmentGUID.txt'
Write-Log "Collected Enrollment GUID : $DeviceEnrollmentID"
Create-Timestamp -RegKeypath 'GetEnrollmentID' -RegKeyName 'EnrollmentID' -RegKeyValue $DeviceEnrollmentID

If (Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseResourceManager\Tracked\$DeviceEnrollmentID")
{
    Remove-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseResourceManager\Tracked\$DeviceEnrollmentID -Recurse -Force
    Write-Log "Delected : `"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseResourceManager\Tracked\$DeviceEnrollmentID`" registry."
}
If (Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments\$DeviceEnrollmentID")
{
    Remove-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments\$DeviceEnrollmentID -Recurse -Force
    Write-Log "Delected : `"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments\$DeviceEnrollmentID`" registry."
}

## Retrieve Scheduled tasks
Write-Log "Checking and deleting Enrollment Scheduled tasks."
Create-Timestamp -RegKeypath 'ScheduledTaskDeletion'
$AllSchdTasks = Get-ScheduledTask | where TaskPath -eq "\Microsoft\Windows\Enterprisemgmt\$DeviceEnrollmentID\"

ForEach ($AllSchdTask in $AllSchdTasks)
{
    $taskname = $AllSchdTask.TaskName
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $AllSchdTask.TaskPath -TaskName $taskname -Confirm:$false
    Write-Log "Deleting : $taskname"
}

Start-Process "$PSScriptRoot\PsExec.exe" -ArgumentList "-is powershell.exe -command Remove-Item 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\Microsoft\Windows\EnterpriseMgmt\$DeviceEnrollmentID' -Recurse -Force" -WindowStyle Hidden


## Removing MDM Certificate
Write-Log "Finding and deleting MDM certificate"
Create-Timestamp -RegKeypath 'MDMCertificateDeletion'
gci cert:\LocalMachine\My -Recurse | Where {$_.Issuer -match 'Microsoft Intune MDM Device CA'} | Remove-Item -Force
$MDMcert = Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My -Recurse | Where {$_.Issuer -match 'Microsoft Intune MDM Device CA'}
If($MDMcert)
{
    Write-Log "MDM Certificate NOT Deleted"
}
Else
{
    Write-Log "MDM Certificate Deleted"
}

## Retrieving existing users
Write-Log "Retrieving Existing user name and deleting Microsoft AAD broker plugin files."
Create-Timestamp -RegKeypath 'DeleteUserFiles'
$UserFolders = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users"
ForEach ($UserFolder in $UserFolders)
{
    if ($UserFolder.Name -ne 'adiadmin')
    {
        if ($UserFolder.Name -ne 'Public')
        {
            if ($UserFolder.Name -ne 'Default')
            {
                $username = $UserFolder.Name
                Write-Log "Deleting Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin files from $username"
                $msaadName = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Packages" -Recurse -Force -Include Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin* -ea SilentlyContinue).Name
                Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Packages\$msaadName\Settings\*" -Force -Recurse -ea SilentlyContinue 
                Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Packages\$msaadName\AC\TokenBroker\Accounts\*" -Force -Recurse -ea SilentlyContinue
            }
        }
    }
}

## Running dsregcmd /leave
Write-Log "Running dsregcmd /leave command"
Create-Timestamp -RegKeypath 'DsRegcmdLeave'
Start-Process -FilePath "dsregcmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/leave" -Verb RunAs
#.\dsregcmd.exe /leave

## Printing Reboot required regkey
Write-Log "Please restart you computer to proceed with next step."
Create-Timestamp -RegKeypath 'Reboot' -RegKeyName 'IsRebootRequired' -RegKeyValue 'Yes'

#Remove-Item -Path C:\temp\PsExec.exe -Force

Write-Log "=========== End of Log - $Stamp =========="
```

Created text file(Server.txt) with the device list having the issue.

Executed CoMgmtFix.Ps1 script which does all the work..

Issue in the above steps is I need to delete device from Azure AD manually. If there any way to delete the device entery from Azure AD via Script itself?

Tried the above stesp but need a way to delete device from Azure AD via Script itself.

Comment: `Remove-AzureADDevice` will work for you. Did you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

> To delete device from Azure AD:

Include `RemoveAzureADDevice` PowerShell script command directly.

Before running the command, you must call `connect-AzureAD` in PowerShell.

```
Remove-AzureADDevice -objectID <objectID>
```

To test, I created a virtual machine windows device in my environment and joined with Azure AD.

[image]

Get the `object ID` from AD joined VM properties by visiting `Azure Active Directory -> Devices -> All Devices` & search for the registered device.

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

**Note:** To remove an Azure AD joined device, you must have *"administrative/owner"* permissions under `Roles & Assignments -> Azure Active Directory`

*Refer* [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureaddevice?view=azureadps-2.0)